# Coffescript/jQuery Function only available in prototype

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I am trying to create an animate function which would be available for every object so in my code I define it like that:

```
$.fn.closeCurtain = ->
    $('.curtain').animate
      height: '65%'
      500
      -> $(this).animate
        height: '0%'
        500
```

Then I would like to call it on a click event which doesn't work, however the function is available in the object prototype.

```
$ ->
  $('.mainMenu ul li a').on('click', -> $(this).closeCurtain())
```

Someone can help me with this?

Comment: Why do you have `$('.curtain')` in your plugin? Shouldn't that be a little more localized? And what are you expecting `this` to be inside the `animate` callback?

Comment: Hi, nope because curtain is a general animation which would be called in each and every page, so I cannot make it local. This have to be 'a' element, I managed to work it already. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Although using the fat arrow is correct, jQuery does have a solution for this, [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

```
.on('click', $.proxy($(this), 'closeCurtain'))
```

Comment: Forivall, Thank you, didn't know that. This issue was already solved, but great to learn new things!

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I had to use the gross form of `=>` to reference the current `this`.

```
.on('click', => $(this).closeCurtain())
```